# If I can say "videos", may I also say "audios"?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, is-it-a-word

*Audio* and *video* seem to me very similar words by usage. I often hear the plural form for *video*, but is there a plural form for *audio*? Can I say *audios*? I've never heard it being used.

Comment: Hmm... Audios amigos!

Comment: Can you say *audios*? I don't know.. try it, record it, and upload it so I can listen to it. Should you say *audios*? Nah. Just say "audio" and the context will facilitate your audience's understanding.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes**, you can. Both *audios* and *videos* [took off in the 1980s](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=audios,%20videos&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but *videos* gained more traction than *audios*, probably because there were already well-established short words to talk about audio recordings (records, 8-tracks, tapes) when video recordings became available on similar recording mediums. However, *[audios](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=audios&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)* is being used [legitimately in print](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22audios%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) and I doubt anyone would be confused as to the meaning if you used it. **So if you like it, use it**.

Answer (score 21):

When you hear a phrase like

> audio and video recording room

both audio and video are being used as uncountable nouns.

So you can't generalise from that context to using the word audios, because the pluralisation would mean that audio is a countable noun.

You can, however, use video as a countable noun. This has come about through typical English speaker laziness: video is short for either [videotape](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/videotape) or [videocassette](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/videocassette) and has come to refer to the single instance contained upon the tape that the video is recoded on.

Typically, to refer to a single instance of audio, you say

> [an/the] audio recording

and in plural

> audio recordings

Audios is not a word in common usage, so it is not advisable to use it.

Unlike video, audio recording media tend to be shortened to the specific medium, e.g.

- audiotape -> tape
- audio cassette -> cassette
- audio CD -> CD

Comment: Also, "(audio) clips" is common in the context of modern audio editing software.

Comment: @Neil: Or tracks.

Comment: @Matt You might want to explain why you *can* say video, though.

Comment: Well, the plural form of video can be videos. As an uncountable noun, video means "the process of recording or showing television programmes, films, real events."

Comment: Not true.  See below.

Comment: @Kyle: that people have used it in incredibly small number does not make it in common use.

Comment: If you google the plural "audios", the results return nearly 52 million hits for the word;  going through the first few pages, i estimate that somewhere around 3/5 of the entries (at least) involve a syntax essentially same to that which the OP was asking about.  Cut that to half as much, or even a third, and you get 10 to 20 million pages that use "audio" in the way the poster asked about.

Some of the sites that use the word as wondered about, above, are the University of Wisconsin and Alcoholics Anonymous.  Seems like a pretty suggestive sample, to me.

Comment: @Kyle: what context do you think the questioner was thinking of using *audios* in?

Comment: Doesn't the question make it clear?  OP says he often hears of "videos", and he's wondering if there is a similar plural of "audios" that is often used in English.  It seems clear to me that he's asking if English speakers use the word "audios" to refer to recorded sounds of various formats, the same way "videos" is.  While it may not be a universally common usage, Google seems to clearly indicate that it is one that is gaining in popularity;  further, with the wide array of formats now available (mp3,CDs,DVDs,DAT,5-channel,Dolby Surround,etc) it stands to reason that it would be.

Comment: +1 Agree. Somebody updated our company website with a section for multimedia and categories for *Videos* and *Audios*. *Audios* just sounds wrong to me, for reasons you mention. *Videos* seemed okay, and once they went with that I can imagine the next logical step was *Audios*, but I would have preferred to use *Video* and *Audio* as uncountable nouns. However, I am from the US, and the person who maintains the site is in Canada. Does that make the difference? They already misspell words like `organisation` and `colour` (har har)